# Supervisor won't see RabbitMQ Running When updating configuration file

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, supervisord

Supervisord seems to work fine with RabbitMQ in the beginning, however, when I do modifications to Supervisord configuration file, and issue `update` command (throught supervisord control utility), it shows this message `FATAL      Exited too quickly (process log may have details)`, albeit the RabbitMQ is already running and handling messages normally.

This is my configuration of Rabbit in supervisor:

```
[program:RabbitMQ]
command = /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopwaitsecs=15
redirect_stderr=true
stopasgroup=true  ;; Stops all the subprocesses using TERM system signal
stderr_logfile = /path/to/log/Rabbit_supervisor_error.log
stdout_logfile = /path/to/log/Rabbit_supervisor_output.log
```

What could be wrong?

**__ EDIT __**

Supervisord as well doesn't stop the services (I have celery workers instances running). Do I miss something I don't understand?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That usually happens because when restarting `RabbitMQ`, it is no longer a child process for `Supervisord`, which makes it uncontrollable using `Supervisord`